# How to display values as different colours in pandas' pivot_table?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I am trying to recreate [this graph](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/output_18_1.png) from [here](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/01/complete-tutorial-learn-data-science-python-scratch-2/)

My code is:

```
impute_grps = data.pivot_table(values=["Loan_Status"], index=[ "Credit_History","Gender"],  
aggfunc='count')
print (impute_grps)
impute_grps.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, color=['red','blue'], grid=False)
```

giving the image below. Can someone tell me how to split loan_status as per the original? i have tried adding it to index but get `ValueError: Grouper for 'Loan_Status' not 1-dimensional` error.

[image]

Comment: I guess you need crosstab somewhere as defined in the link you shared. "temp3 = pd.crosstab(df['Credit_History'], df['Loan_Status'])"